# Libraries and drivers for speech-to-speech translation using Google APIs

Tags: docker, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, fastapi, audio-streaming

I'm trying to deploy FastAPI of speech to speech translation using Google speech-to-text and then text-to-speech APIs in GCP Kubernetes Engine (GKE). I've tried to use pyaudio, pulseaudio, pydub, ALSA, and have tried using alsa-config yaml file. Below are the configMap file and a snap of dockerfile through which I'm trying to install libraries. After deploying to Kubernetes in Google I'm able to access and see the UI (swagger) of Created FastAPI but i'm not able to do speech-to-speech translation (the code works in local machine). I realized that the code is not able to connect to host machine (windows OS) audio devices.

1. Wondering if there is any other library that i'm missing to be used here. Or, any suggestions on drivers to be used?
2. Also, is it a good idea to go with kubernetes? I read in chatGPT that making audio work in docker environment is really tough. Do you suggest any other architecture or way of deploying? I'm creating FastAPI backend to be used by front end as a teams app. Note that the code works in local machine.

alsa-config.yaml

```
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: alsa-config
data:
  .asoundrc: |
    pcm.!default {
      type asym
      playback.pcm {
        type plug
        slave.pcm "hw:0,0"
      }
      capture.pcm {
        type plug
        slave.pcm "hw:0,0"
      }
    }
    options.samplerate = 16000
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.9-slim-buster

ENV PULSE_SERVER=127.0.0.1
ENV PULSE_ID=1000

# Installing build essentials and necessary libraries
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y gcc --no-install-recommends build-essential && \
    apt-get clean && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends pulseaudio python-pyaudio python3-pyaudio \
        #python-gnuradio-audio-portaudio alsa-base #alsa is the default audio driver in Ubuntu, pulseaudio is a higher level audio driver
        portaudio19-dev alsa-utils libasound2-dev libportaudio2 libportaudiocpp0 libsndfile1-dev \
        libpulse0 pulseaudio-utils libpulse-dev \
        ffmpeg 
        #winealsa pyalsaaudio \
        #build-essential \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*


# Making a directory /app and setting it as work directory
RUN mkdir /app
WORKDIR /app

ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
ENV PIP_ROOT_USER_ACTION=ignore

# Copy files to /app folder
#COPY . /app
COPY requirements.txt /app/requirements.txt
COPY media_translation_api_key.json /app/media_translation_api_key.json
COPY storage-bucket-key.json /app/storage-bucket-key.json
COPY alsa-config.yaml /app/alsa-config.yaml

###########......Install pip within the virtual environment
RUN python -m pip install --no-cache-dir --trusted-host files.pythonhosted.org --trusted-host pypi.org --trusted-host pypi.python.org -r /app/requirements.txt --upgrade pip

# Copy the script containg speech-to-speech code with 
COPY FastAPI_scipt.py /app/FastAPI_scipt.py
COPY main.py /app/main.py

WORKDIR /app

RUN python -m pip install --upgrade google-cloud-speech
RUN python -m pip install --upgrade google-api-python-client

# Set the environment variable for the Streamlit command
ENV LANG=C.UTF-8 \
    LC_ALL=C.UTF-8 \
    PATH=$PATH:/app \
    HOST=0.0.0.0 \
    PORT=8000


# Expose the port on which the app will run
EXPOSE 8000

CMD ["uvicorn", "main:app",  "--reload", "--host", "0.0.0.0", "--port", "8000"]
VOLUME ["/etc/alsa"]
```

Comment: A container runs in an isolated environment and can't usually access host devices at all.  You mention that the program works running directly on the host; just do that.  As a typically-remote clustered container environment, Kubernetes is not a good match for your needs.

Comment: I do feel that kubernetes could make it hard but I learnt that there are some ways of enabling virtual environments access audio devices of host machine. Infact there are some software libraries. ALSA, pulse audio, WASAPI etc.

Comment: For Kubernetes in particular, it's usually running on an arbitrary-selected node in a cluster somewhere else.  If the host machine does have audio devices, it's not going to be the local system.  I suspect you're looking for some sort of client-side approach to capture audio that you can plug into a server application.  Also see the SO [help/on-topic], though; "what library should I use" is explicitly considered off-topic.